# Ramda search array if element not found add it to the list

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

I have an array of items in my redux store. I need to write a function using Ramda where I go through an array, if I don't find an element with an id, I add this element to the array. For example,

```
array=[{id: 1, value: true}, {id: 2, value: false}]

element = {id: 3, value: false}
```

This would return:

```
array=[{id: 1, value: true}, {id: 2, value: false}, {id: 3, value: false}]
```

Another example:

```
array=[{id: 1, value: true}, {id: 2, value: false}]

element = {id: 1, value: true}
```

This would return:

```
array=[{id: 1, value: true}, {id: 2, value: false}]
```

I was trying something like this, but it does not work:

```
pipe(
        path(["array"]),
        findIndex(propEq("id", element.id)),
        ifElse(
          identity,
          pipe(over(["array"], append(element))),
          evolve({
            array: append(element)
          })
        )
      )(array);
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working as expected with your code? Can you elaborate what the issue is?

Comment: `identity` won't work as `findIndex` returns `-1` if not in array

Comment: if in the 2nd example the array were `array=[{id: 1, value: false}, {id: 2, value: false}]` would the result still have the first value as `true`?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
const array=[{id: 1, value: true}, {id: 2, value: false}]

const element = {id: 1, value: false}
const {
  pipe,
  findIndex,
  propEq,
  ifElse,
  identity,
  over,
  append,
  evolve,
  equals, 
  flip, 
  update
} = require('ramda')
const result = 
  pipe(
    findIndex(propEq("id", element.id)),
    ifElse(
      equals(-1),
      ()=>append(element, array),
      (i) => update(i, element, array),
      )
    )(array)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `R.any` with `R.eqProps()` to check if an object with the same `id` exists in the array. `R.any` returns a boolean, so it works better as a predicate. In addition, if the object exists at index 0 in the array, the returned 0 would be casted to `false`. Unless one exists, append the object to the array:

```js
const { curry, unless, any, eqProps, append } = R

const fn = curry((obj, arr) => 
  unless(
    any(eqProps('id', obj)), // check if the obj id exists in the array
    append(obj) // append obj if it doesn't
  )(arr)
)

const array = [{id: 1, value: true}, {id: 2, value: false}]

console.log(fn({id: 3, value: false})(array))
console.log(fn({id: 1, value: true})(array))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the item is present in the array by passing `propEq` as a predicate function to `any`. You can use ternary operator `?` to  return the original array, or use `append` to add the new item,  based on result of predicate function condition that is: "is the new element id already present in the original array"?

```js
const {propEq,append,any } = R;
const addIfNotFound = (arr, el) =>
  any(propEq('id', el.id))(arr) ? arr : append(el, arr);
const array = [{id: 1, value: true}, {id: 2, value: false}];
const itemToAdd = {id: 3, value: false};
const itemToIgnore = {id: 1, value: true};

const arr1 = addIfNotFound(array, itemToAdd);
const arr2 = addIfNotFound(array, itemToIgnore);
console.log( "arr1 with item added:" ,arr1 );
console.log( "arr2 without item added:" ,arr2 );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```